# Increase font size of H4 within product description tab css - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I need to increase the font size of H4's within the product description tab on a woocommerce site. I can change the colour but not increase size.

I have tried the following:

1)

```
.woocommerce .tabs .h4 { 
        font-size: 32px!important;
}
```

This changes all the text on the website but not on the product page:

2)

```
p { font-size: 32px !important;

}
```

These do nothing:

3)

```
.product-category h4 {
font-size: 32px !important;

}
```

4. .woocommerce ul.products li.product .description {
   font-size: 32px !important;
   font-weight: bold !important;
   }
5. .product-categories li a {font-size: 32px!important;
   }
6. .woocommerce .tabs .h4 {
   font-size: 32px!important;
   }
7. `.single-product-content .entry-title { font-size: 28px; }`
8. .product-categories li a {
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: normal;
   margin-top: 15px;
   }
9. entry h4 {
   font-size: 32px !important;
   font-weight: bold !important;
   }

I thought by using this code and the !important would override the theme font size but it didn't.

Updated note: it doesn't have to be h4 it can be paragraph text - really, anything. I have searched high and low and can find how to change the tab titles but nothing about the contents of the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is overridden by some other styles. If you can provide the live URL to the Store or if local the NGROK link etc. so I can see the CSS which is overriding your CSS? Because without proper information it would not be easy to debug.

**Solution** **.woocommerce-tabs .woocommerce-Tabs-panel p span**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is one of the product pages: https://www.lacefronts.com.au/product/lace-front-human-hair-wig-light-blonde-bob-with-bangs-wig-6-inch-bron/

I need to increase the font size under description.

Comment: .woocommerce-tabs .woocommerce-Tabs-panel p span - with this, you can increase font sizes as per your needs just change p with your desired tag. If any further help is needed you can comment below. If this solves your issue an upvote is very helpful to others